# Boostrap 4 tooltip not showing on dynamically-loaded elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

The tooltips showing are the default looking tooltips instead of the bootstrap 4 ones.

The tooltips I get:

[image]

vs. the tooltips I should get:

[image]

I activate the tooltips in the head section with this as required by Boostrap (4.5.0):

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
    });
</script>
```

The thing is that when I run this exact command in the console of the devtools, it activates them alright and the right tooltip shows up.
Anyone knows what is interfering ?

Here is my full head section:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <title>Test | Results</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-ujbKXb9V3HdK7jcWL6kHL1c+2Lj4MR4Gkjl7UtwpSHg/ClpViddK9TI7yU53frPN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.6.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/pdb-component-library/js/pdbe-molstar-plugin-1.2.1.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link href="../../css/custom_features.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/pdb-component-library/css/pdbe-molstar-1.2.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/rcsb-molstar.css">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#header").load("../../pages/header_job.html");
            $("#footer").load("../../pages/footer_job.html");
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        });

    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you show as well where you apply it? Are you getting any error messages on the console?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally found the solution.
The problem comes from the fact that the tooltips are on elements that are loaded in javascript.
So the general function to activate the tooltips do not work, I need to use

```js
$("#id").load("./html.txt", function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```